# How to use SwingWorker in this example

Tags: java, jtable, swingworker

I have class for reading file and upload information inside `JTable`, So when you have something like that, your application will become so slow and you will have to use `SwingWorker`. i tried to follow one of my friend [SwingWorker][1] tutor and sun API, but this is the first time of seeing SwingWorker even first time to know about it, so i tried to  copy the tutor but of course there is an issue the code is posted

my way was by changing the original code. (the first block of code)  To the other

```
    private DefaultTableModel createModel(String srtPath) {
        //int maxLine = ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath);  // debug
        //Object[][] data = new Object[maxLine][];
        //System.out.println(maxLine);  // debug
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
            //System.out.println(lins.get(i)+" "+starts.get(i)+" "+ ends.get(i)+" "+ subs.get(i));
            model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
        }
        return model;
```

code after changing **Edited[2]**

```
 class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath;
       private final JTable table;
       DefaultTableModel model;
        public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
                this.srtPath = srtPath;
                 this.table = table;
             }

      protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground(String srtPath)  {
     model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
    }
    return model;
}
    @Override
protected void done() {
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
}
}
```

the action code **Edited[2]**

```
     Action openAction = new AbstractAction("Open Subtitle", openIcon) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ourFileSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            ourFileSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
            ourSrtFile =  ourFileSelector.getSelectedFile();
            srtPath = ourSrtFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Worker p = new Worker(srtPath, table);
            p.extecute();
            /*
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
            columnA.setMinWidth(10);
            columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
            TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
            columnB.setMinWidth(80);
            columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
            TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
            columnC.setMinWidth(80);
            columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
                    */
        }
    };
```

after changing the code i am getting this error and it say implements all abstract method
**Edited[2]**

```
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AnimeAid\src\animeaid\GuiInterface.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
                p.extecute();
  symbol:   method extecute()
  location: variable p of type GuiInterface.Worker
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AnimeAid\src\animeaid\GuiInterface.java:240: error: GuiInterface.Worker is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground() in SwingWorker
     class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
Note: C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AnimeAid\src\animeaid\GuiInterface.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AnimeAid\nbproject\build-impl.xml:920: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\isslam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AnimeAid\nbproject\build-impl.xml:260: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

the full class

```
   public class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
    String[] columnNames = {"#", "Start", "End", "Translation column"};

    JComboBox laList;  
    ReadFile reader;
    private final int numberOfButton = 6;
    private final JTable table;
    JToolBar toolBar;
    private final JTextField enterText,startTime,endTime;
    private final JMenu jMenu1,jMenu2,jMenu3;
    private final JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private final JMenuItem itemNewSrt,itemOpenVideo,itemSavefile;
    private static JFileChooser ourFileSelector,ourVideoSelector;
    File ourVideoFile,ourSrtFile;
    Border Campound,empty,Boveld,etch;
    private final JLabel startTimeingLable,endTimeingLabel;
    public static String  mediaPath="",srtPath="";
    Canvas c;
    ImageIcon[] icon;
    JButton[] Obutton;
   static final int COLUMN = 4 ; 



         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
       {
           //ReadFile.readSubtitles();
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GuiInterface("");

            }

        });

}



    public GuiInterface(String title){

    //reader = new ReadFile();

    setSize(1024, 720);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("AnimeFactor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(GuiInterface.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //video setting 
    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    c = new Canvas();
    String[] petStrings = { "Translation Line", "Both Line" };
    laList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
    mediaPlayer.playMedia("C:\\Users\\isslam\\Downloads\\gg.mp4");
    table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
        columnC.setMinWidth(80);
        columnC.setMaxWidth(90);


    ImageIcon openIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/folder-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/red-disk-icon.png"));
        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(
                GuiInterface.class.getResource("/resources/image/Actionsnew-icon.png"));




        Action openAction = new AbstractAction("Open Subtitle", openIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ourFileSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                ourFileSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
                ourSrtFile =  ourFileSelector.getSelectedFile();
                srtPath = ourSrtFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Worker p = new Worker(srtPath, table);
                p.extecute();
                DefaultTableModel model = p.get();
                table.setModel(model);
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
                table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
                TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
                columnA.setMinWidth(10);
                columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
                TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
                columnB.setMinWidth(80);
                columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
                TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
                columnC.setMinWidth(80);
                columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
            }
        };

        Action saveAction = new AbstractAction("Save", saveIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        };
        Action newAction = new AbstractAction("New", newIcon) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("New File");
            }
        };
    jMenu1 = new JMenu("File");
    jMenu2 = new JMenu("Video");
    jMenu3 = new JMenu("Subtitle");
    itemNewSrt = new JMenuItem(newAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemNewSrt);
    itemSavefile = new JMenuItem(saveAction);
    jMenu1.add(itemSavefile);
    jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
    jMenuBar1.setBorder(etch);
    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);


    Obutton = new JButton[numberOfButton];
    etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
    enterText = new JTextField();
    enterText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,100));
    ourFileSelector = new JFileChooser();
    startTime = new JTextField();
    startTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    startTimeingLable = new JLabel("Starting Time");
    endTimeingLabel = new JLabel("Ending Time");
    endTime = new JTextField();
    endTime.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 20));
    toolBar = new JToolBar();
        //toolBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        toolBar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
        toolBar.add(newAction);
        toolBar.add(saveAction);


        JPanel toolBarPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        toolBarPane.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel timing = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        timing.add(startTimeingLable);
        timing.add(startTime);
        timing.add(endTimeingLabel);
        timing.add(endTime);
        timing.add(laList);

        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 5, 5, 5);
        Boveld = BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
        Campound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty,Boveld);


        JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        textFiled.add(timing);
        textFiled.add(enterText,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        textFiled.setBorder(Campound);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(textFiled, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(toolBarPane,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);




        //Container cp = getContentPane();
       toolBar.add(openAction);
       itemOpenVideo = new JMenuItem(openAction);
       jMenu1.add(itemOpenVideo);
       //itemOpenVideo.addActionListener(new MenuBarMethod());

    }

    private DefaultTableModel createModel(String srtPath) {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
        ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {

            model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
        }
        return model;
    }

    class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath;
       private final JTable table;
        public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
                this.srtPath = srtPath;
                 this.table = table;
             }

      protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground(String srtPath) throws InterruptedException {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    ArrayList<String> ends = ReadFile.getFileEndingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> starts = ReadFile.getFileStartingTime(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> subs = ReadFile.readSubtitles(srtPath);
    ArrayList<String> lins = ReadFile.ArraylineLengths(srtPath);
    for (int i = 0; i < ReadFile.maxLine(srtPath); i++) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] {lins.get(i), starts.get(i), ends.get(i), subs.get(i)});
    }
    return model;
}
    @Override
protected void done() {
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
    columnA.setMinWidth(10);
    columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
    TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
    columnB.setMinWidth(80);
    columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
    TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
    columnC.setMinWidth(80);
    columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
}
}


public class MenuBarMethod implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        Object buttonPressed=a.getSource();
       if(buttonPressed.equals(itemOpenVideo)){
        ourVideoSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        ourVideoSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
        ourVideoFile = ourVideoSelector.getSelectedFile();
        mediaPath = ourVideoFile.getAbsolutePath();
       }
    }

}

}
```

i have issue in this lines

```
protected void done() {
table.setModel(model);//because model are local
```

also this part

```
 p.extecute();
 DefaultTableModel model = p.get()
```

here it say make the class abstract

```
 class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void>
```

also you declared jtable again but in the contractor of the gui class it is declared

Comment: @peeskillet can you take a look at this issue i think you going to understand this issue

Comment: @peeskillet can you say any thing about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Immediate fix

From [documentation of `SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

> **Type Parameters:**
>
> T - the result type returned by this
>   SwingWorker's doInBackground and get methods
>   V - the type used for
>   carrying out intermediate results by this SwingWorker's publish and
>   process methods

So replace

```
class Process extends SwingWorker<String, String>
```

with

```
class Process extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void>
```

**Note:**

- It's better if you rename your class from `Process`, there is already a class named `[Process][2]` in java.
- You have to pass the `String` via `SwingWorker`'s constructor. (In this case, have it as a member of `Process` class and pass it in constructor.

---

### Calling the `SwingWorker`

In your `actionPerformed` method, replace

```
DefaultTableModel model = createModel(srtPath);
```

with

```
Process p = new Process(srtPath);
p.extecute();
DefaultTableModel model = p.get();
// Rest of actionPerformed content.
```

---

### Doing it in background

Now everything is working, but you have not achieved the desired effect. The ui thread is still waiting for the output.

- Make `execute` method last thing to do in `actionPerformed` method. (Ui thread will be released.)
- Everything else after getting returned `DefaultModel` should be put in overridden `done` method of `SwingWorker` (`Process`). (You need to pass required objects from constructor).

  ```
  @Override
  protected void done() {
      table.setModel(model);
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
      table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
      TableColumn columnA = table.getColumn("#");
      columnA.setMinWidth(10);
      columnA.setMaxWidth(40);
      TableColumn columnB= table.getColumn("Start");
      columnB.setMinWidth(80);
      columnB.setMaxWidth(90);
      TableColumn columnC= table.getColumn("End");
      columnC.setMinWidth(80);
      columnC.setMaxWidth(90);
  }
  ```

  You have to pass `table` object from constrictor of `Process`.

Therefore in `actionPerformed`,

```
    Process p = new Process(srtPath, table);
    p.execute();
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**
Constructor would be like following.

class Worker extends SwingWorker {

```
   private String srtPath;
   private JTable table;

   public Worker(String srtPath, JTable table) {
       this.srtPath = srtPath;
       this.table = table;
   }

   // Other methods.
}
```

Comment: both are giving error it say create subclass next to override and other are the same

Comment: also it say class Worker extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Void> {
       private final String srtPath//srtPath are not used

Comment: when i run the application it say java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - AnimeAid.GuiInterface.Worker is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground() in javax.swing.SwingWorker
 at AnimeAid.GuiInterface.<clinit>(GuiInterface.java:240)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Comment: The error message says it all. Compiler is not recognizing doInBackground method as overridden from SwingWorker class. Did you add @Override ? Also, are you by any chance using netbeans?

Comment: yes i add it and i am using netBeans do you wanna me to change to IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.1

Comment: any idea to finish this issue

Comment: Your code is fine. It's a netbeans issue as my guess was right that you are using netbeans. Go to netbeans project properties, in the compile options, uncheck "compile on save", then "clean and build" the project, then recheck "compile on save". The problem should go away. Hopefully

Comment: nothing wrong with compile on save it is only for compiling with out run the application there is wrong with the code very small one i will up vote you answer but try to help me in this plz

Comment: if you don't have any idea tell me so i can ask new question about override

Comment: did you or did you not add `@Override` annotation on doInBackground ? if yes, you should post a question.

Comment: yes i did thank you i will mark you answer as right one

Comment: aha... It's a spelling mistake. You wrote `extecute` in stead of `execute` !!! :D

Comment: It was a typo in my answer

Comment: better post it.. it should be a minor issue, but people squinting at the same code generally overlook small things :) good luck